# What are most relevant project management complements free in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, project-site

Im checking to install a project management complement, and searching about they i found *workpoint365* and *kanbanboard* i need know they are nice complements or not and what are most relevant project management complements free.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a solution called Kanbo which might do the trick for you in terms of interface and features. They should have a trial version or something. PS. I have no ties with Kanbo.